# VS Extensions development: How to apply vs theme colors to textbox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I placed texbox and checkbox to tool window, but its default colors (background/foreground) do not match visual studio theme.
What is easiest way to apply visual studio theme color to textbox background?

[image: Tool Window view in case of Dark theme]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't apply a style to your controls, then they should automatically take on the style of the Visual Studio theme. I also had a bit of trouble with this, as I wanted to set some control properties via styles. Instead of creating a "button style", I had to instead define each property (margin, padding, width, etc.) as it's own resource key and set them each individually in every control. It sucks, but it did the job. For more information and a code example, [check out my answer I gave to my question here on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c57e20fb-ee7b-40cd-8318-9f262ff4ca30/how-to-have-visual-studio-extensions-controls-extend-the-vs-theme?forum=vsx).